# Eclipse custom breakpoint (execute a java method, do not halt)

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-plugin

I am looking to instrument a near-production application to simply print the stack trace when a variable is modified.   I don't want to halt-thread or halt-VM.

What is a best and least complex approach?
Do I need to write my own plugin to handle 'DebugElement'?
Do I need to write a custom Debug Adapter?

Are there any examples out there?  I know about [EclipseCon2005_Tutorial21-v2](https://www.eclipsecon.org/2005/presentations/EclipseCon2005_Tutorial21.zip) (Darin Wright, Bjorn Freeman-Benson) example for an Eclipse debug plugin contains deprecated code (e.g., "IPluginDescriptor").

I'm trying to follow [Vogella's tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugFramework/article.html) but some things are not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, just call a method from the conditional expression.  It can do what is needed, and then "return false;" so that the VM is not suspended.